# Testing my flair

Tags: support

The MO user's page has a button flair. I didn't know where and how to test it. Thus I have to decided to do it here, at least temporarily. I have copied the snipped mentioned in the explanation (if it works then you may try it too), and let's see what happens:

[image: profile for Włodzimierz Holsztyński at MathOverflow, Q&A for professional mathematicians]

It works! ...except that I don't see how to change my flair, i.e. the color. But at least let me change the size:

[image: profile for Włodzimierz Holsztyński at MathOverflow, Q&A for professional mathematicians]

Great, but where is the rest of my last name. Let me fix it (it'll be a patch): ...--no, I don't know how to do it. Well, it was fun, I guess. Now my:

> **META-QUESTION**   Should I remove this post?

**EDIT**   Now I might change the color (after another look at the same instruction, this time thanks to @Emil--thank you):

[image: profile for Włodzimierz Holsztyński at MathOverflow, Q&A for professional mathematicians]

YES!!! :-) Inside the snippet, at the end of the image URL, say:

"https://mathoverflow.net/users/flair/8385.png"

one needs to add "?theme=dark" (for a *dark* flair), so that the needed resulting image link would be:

"https://mathoverflow.net/users/flair/8385.png?theme=dark"

Comment: You might as well keep the post here.  People might want to hit the "edit" button to see how you did what you did .

Comment: Or, they might want go to the flair tab on their own profile, where they get the explanation, a ready-made code including the proper user ID, and a description of the available customization options.

Comment: Let's copy the same flair code snippet here, and see whar happens: <a href="http://mathoverflow.net/users/8385/w%c5%82odzimierz-holszty%c5%84ski">
<img src="http://mathoverflow.net/users/flair/8385.png" width="208" height="58" alt="profile for Włodzimierz Holsztyński at MathOverflow, Q&amp;A for professional mathematicians" title="profile for Włodzimierz Holsztyński at MathOverflow, Q&amp;A for professional mathematicians">
</a>

Comment: At least we see the code. *Width & height* can be controlled, while I don't see any way to change the *color*.

Comment: Finally, this time I payed attention to the instruction, to some small extra info. Thank you @EmilJeřábek.

Comment: Note that changing the default size is not really advisable. The flair thing is a low-resolution bitmap image, hence any resizing makes it blurry (or pixelated, depending on the parameters and the underlying anti-aliasing technology).

Comment: Is this question just a flair sandbox?